# Android:ViewFlipper animation

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have add a ViewFlipper in which has 2 linearlayout,and I have made an animation xml:
left_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

right_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

left_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

right_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

the "Next" button in one linearlayout which shows when first load the app:

```
mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
                //mViewFlipper.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.left_in));
                mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.left_in));
                mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.right_out));
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
            }

        });
```

and  the "Prev" button:

```
mPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.right_in));
            mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.left_out));
            mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }       
    });
```

The "Next" Button goes well, But the "Prev" Button goes strange: when I click the "prev",it first change into the previous view and then start the animation ,and at last it changes into the Previous view again! How to solve it??
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`setOutAnimation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setOutAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) and [`setInAnimation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setInAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29).

Comment: But when I press the other button(which show the Previous),it goes strange:the current view change into the previous one and then start the animation! Why?

Comment: On the second button, you switched the animations in your `setOutAnimation()` and `setInAnimation()`.

Comment: Nothing changed when you put the `R.anim.left_out` on your `setOutAnimation()` and the `R.anim.right_in` on your `setInAnimation()`?  I'm not talking about the order of the statements.

Answer (score 3):

Well this a very old post. but still the fix is here:

you need to call `viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(null)` and `viewFlipper.setInAnimation(null)` to reset the animation .

```
   @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        if (v.equals(mNext))
        {
            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(null);

             mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(null);
              mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.left_in));

        vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.right_out));

            mViewFlipper.showNext();

        }
        else if (v.equals(mPrev))
        {

            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(null);

             mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(null);

            mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.right_in));

        mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.left_out));

             mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }

        }
```